# How to view authorize net using TLS 1.2

Tags: java, ssl, tls1.2, authorize.net

Am new to Authorize NET. My application is developed with Java and integrated with authorize NET.Now Authorize NET have sent a mail that Authorize NET TLS need to upgrade to 1.2. My support team have done the changes. But i need to verify the version when doing transaction in test mode. Is there any possible way to see them. Like logging or get TLS details from response.

```
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose
```

I have configured as like above in Tomcat server. But it doesn't print any values..